How to Check if a Constructor is Explicitly-Defaulted
For example:
struct X {
    X(){/***/}
    X(const int& ){/***/}
    X(      int&&){/***/}
    X(const X& ) = default;
    X(      X&&) = default;
    X& operator=(const X& ){/***/}
    X& operator=(      X&&){/***/}
};

Class X is not trivial and is not an aggregate.
Checking the source code of class X is not an option (although it is known which constructors and operators are available).

What is the actual question/use-case you are interested in?

I want to know if the constructor is explicitly-defaulted, instead of user-provided (i.e., user-defined), deleted, not defined at all, etc.

But why do you need to know that? What is the underlying and actual problem that knowledge would solve?

@JL In any case, AFAIK there is no standard library type trait or compiler intrinsic that can give you the information you are looking for. You will likely need an external script to parse the source code.

Kinda https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible etc? It CAn'T differ  explicit default from trivial in general case, becuase they have same semantic, thereis no difference between them. But in context where you have non-trivial default constructor trival copy may exist only if "explicitly defaulted".

@Swift-FridayPie So in this example, if I know that the default constructor is not trivial (I might know it), I just need to prove that the copy constructor is trivial in order to verify that it is explicitly defaulted? Otherwise it would not exist, is that how it works?

@Someprogrammerdude I need to know if the C++ language provides the capability to identify these cases. What would be the consequences to have a copy constructor like this instead X(const X& ) {}?

@RemyLebeau I guess your second comment is the best answer, i.e., that it is not possible. Thanks.

By the way, I see 2 votes to close this question. From my point of view, this is a valid question about a language feature/ability. In fact, it shows a limitation in the knowledge you can have, regardless it is found useless by some people, that is exactly what I needed to know.

@JL I voted to close as "Needs Details or Clarity" since is it still not clear WHY you need this. In any case, X(const X& ) {} is a valid copy constructor as far as the signature goes, the lack of a body is more of a runtime logic issue, and a compile-time check is not going to help you with that.

Unfortunately, your question is an XY problem. You you have a solution that you need help with, but you don't tell us the problem it's supposed to actually solve. Perhaps there are other possible solutions? If you ask about the actual and underlying problem directly, and tell us about the solution you thought of, then we could help you much better.

The above code is just an example, it is not solving anything. The question I wanted to answer, for other purposes that are out of the scope and not relevant here, is if it is possible to check if a constructor is explicitly-defaulted in general, that is, if the C++ language supports that. I could not find a way to do it so that is why I asked here (although I suspected it might not be possible). Now I think it is confirmed it is not possible, so thanks to everyone for the help :)

There is no trait in the library for this. It isn't possible to check with the help of the core language either.
